# PHP IRC Bot Undefined Offset

Tags: php, undefined, offset, bots

I'm building a IRC bot in PHP. The error it gives me is for lines 45 & 50 with the error "Undefined offset: 4 in /****/***/***/Grue.php on line 50"

Here's those lines:
Line 45: `$command = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $this -> ex[3]);`

Line 50: `switch($this -> ex[4]) {`

Here's he rest of the code:

```
<?php
//So the bot doesn't stop.
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

//Sample connection.
$config = array('server' => 'irc.foonetic.net', 'port' => 6667, 'channel' => '#lingubender', 'name' => 'KiBot', 'nick' => 'Grue', 'pass' => '',);  

class Grue {
var $socket; // TCP/IP Connection
var $ex = array(); // Messages

function __construct($config)
{
    $this -> socket = fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port']);
    $this -> login($config);
    $this -> main($config);
}
/* Log into server
@param array
*/
function login($config)
{
    $this -> write_data('USER', $config['nick'].' :'.$config['name']);
    $this -> write_data('NICK', $config['nick']);
    $this -> enter_channel($config['channel']);
}

//* Grabs/displays data
function main($config)
{
    $data = fgets($this -> socket, 256);

    echo nl2br($data);

    flush();

    $this -> ex = explode(' ', $data);

    if ($this -> ex[0] == 'PING') {
        write_data('PONG', $this -> ex[1]); 
    }

    $command = str_replace(array(chr(10), chr(13)), '', $this -> ex[3]);

    strtolower($command);

    if ($command == ':grue' || ':gu') {
        switch($this -> ex[4]) {
            case 'join':
                enter_channel($this -> ex[5]);
                break;

            case 'part':
                $this -> write_data('PART'.$this -> ex[5].' :', $this -> ex[6]);
                break;

            case 'repeat':
                $message = "";

                for ($i = 5; $i <= (count($this -> ex)); $i++) {
                    $message .= $this -> ex[$i]." ";    
                }

                $this -> write_data('PRIVMSG '.$this -> ex[4].' :', $message);
                break;

            case 'restart':
                echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5\">";
                exit;

            case 'shutdown':
                $this -> write_data('QUIT', $this -> ex[5]);
                exit;
        }
    }
    $this -> main($config);
}

function write_data($cmd, $msg = null) {
    if ($msg == null) {
        fputs($this -> socket, $cmd."\r\n");
        echo '<strong>'.$cmd.'</strong><br>';   
    } else {
        echo '<strong>'.$cmd.' '.$msg.'</strong><br>';
    }
} function enter_channel($channel) {
    if (is_array($channel)) {
        foreach ($channel as $chan) {
            $this -> write_data('JOIN', $chan); 
        }
    } else {
        $this -> write_data('JOIN', $channel);
    }   
}
}

$bot = new Grue($config);
?>
```

I've checked all the brackets, and parenthesis; Everything I could think of didn't work. If it helps, when I ran it it played over the above errors (45 & 50) about 60 times.

Comment: It means that in the context where it is run, `$this->ex[4]` (or 3) doesn't exist, you're trying to access an array element which doesn't exist, hence the error. You should print a debug stack (`print_r(debug_backtrace())`) and see where it leads.

Comment: Also, I have a working PHP IRC bot, which is quite a bit more sophisticated than yours (each user is an object, each channel is an object, good dynamic user tracking and channel monitoring, connection works, etc), if you want I can share it with you.

Comment: **[Here you go](http://pastebin.com/xVDiDn94)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see several problems in your code, I'll try to address them and offer solutions:

- You are using recoursive functions. The `main` method should include a while loop:

  ```
  while (!feof($this->socket)) {

      ...
      ...
      ...

  }
  ```

  This way the script will end when the socket connection dies.
- Your PING PONG will fail. You are calling the method without `$this->`.
- You're not lowering the command's case. You need to assign `strtolower($command)` to something (`$command = strtolower($command);` maybe?)
- Your condition is always true. `if ($command == ":grue" || ":gu")` `":gu"` is always true. `if ($command == ":grue" || $command == ":gu")` maybe?

Other than that, you should have each command with a method.

As for the error, try to `var_dump($this->ex)` when the error occurs, also print a `print_r(debug_backtrace())`, to see exactly what function was called when the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this:

```
if ($command == ':grue' || ':gu') {
```

should be:

```
if ($command == ':grue' || $command == ':gu') {
```

and for the offset error you should be checking if its set first:

```
if (isset($this -> ex[4]))
```

Comment: Thanks also. Didn't know there was a problem with the IF(OR) statement.

Answer (score 0):

That error message indicates you're trying to get an element on the array that doesn't exist; for example, you have an array with 3 elements and you're trying to get the 5th element.

In your specific case, as `$this->ex` is generated by using explode, you can say the exploded text doesn't have the quantity of parts you are expecting. I'd suggest you use `var_dump($this->ex)` after doing the explode, so you can get an idea of how is your text being separated and why is it not what you expected.

Comment: Thank you. Helped me see what was going into ex[3] before it executed said command.